# What are the pros and cons to using USART for debugging embedded systems?

Tags: uart

What's are the pros and cons (if any) for using USART to debug embedded systems. What other methods work effectively?  I know different peripherals have different techniques.
**edit**
What if you recorded all data to debug but transmit it after the section   your debugging finishes executing (to prevent overhead)?

Comment: re: edit, how much RAM have you got? That could be a **lot** of data. Also probably a lot of code, which may require debugging to get it right...

Comment: 8KB ram @Colin__s

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: You're getting downvoted because you haven't given us enough information. You need to specify the application, because in certain applications USART would work, in some it won't. What is your application that you are debugging? and what information do you want to return?

Comment: @Makoto I am currently debugging AT commands that are being sent VIA through USART to ESP8266 but I wondered if there were more efficient ways.

Answer (score 1):

UART: simple, low cost, real time, and tons of examples. Slow, logic fixed at run time / inflexible, limited scope and takes up a resource.

Debugger: fast, flexible, powerful / feature rich. RTT and jscope for example are to die for. Expensive, dedicated and cannot do real time unless go with fancier hardware.

Personally I'm a big fan of a hardware debugger.

Answer (score 1):

There is no single/correct answer to your question and I expect it to be closed because it is a matter of opinion...

It really comes down to personal choice and/or what is available on the system you are using.  Sometimes you have a jtag or similar debug interface and no uart/led/other.  Sometimes you have a scope and some gpio, sometimes you have a uart and something to hook it up to to see what comes out.  You could abstract your code and instead of sending the code out the uart, change the back end and log it in ram, then dump it with a debugger later.

All of the solutions should be obvious.  If you add uart code you are adding code, uarts are relatively slow, so your code may end up having delays printing stuff out, these delays may cause problems later as they may be helping some peripheral or other settle, etc, and when you remove the uart printout code you lose that delay now your codes timing is off.  At the same time if you dont have good visibility into what is going on it is very hard without a uart.

An led is a one bit output, you can blink it you can try to make morse code or some other scheme to visually sequence data/bits out, you could just bit bang that gpio pin at uart speeds with a uart protocol and have better visibility.

For a new to me chip the led is the first tool, it tells me code is booting and running, if I can blink it, awesome.  Next I find a timer and try to carefully control the gpio timing.  Confirming that the oscillator I think it is using it is using, can use that led and a stopwatch/timer to  setup the pll, switch to an external oscillator, etc.  With that knowledge now I can compute the divisor for the uart and have a pretty good of being right on or a power of two off.  Then get the uart up, and use the uart from there to further develop the application.

You will find that some products keep the uart code in there (Amazon Dash buttons for example).

It comes down to what you find the easiest or best or what is available.  Get some cortex-m based microcontroller eval board (can get a good one for $10, dozens to chose from from various vendors wont list here) you will often have usb to SWD (like jtag, gets you into the debugger), a virtual uart to the target mcu, and some way to program the mcu in addition to an swd solution.  Not that non-arms dont have this but many of the arm eval boards do.  they often have an led too.  so you can try it all for $10, led blinking debugging, uart debugging, on chip debugger debugging, go find a scope and use that for debugging.  start to develop a personal preference but keep the alternatives in your back pocket as there are times you may need them.

Comment: Check my edit and I currently have an stm32 f1 and have been using Leds to display data. It's kind of pain and I wanted to try USART.

Comment: you answered your own question, what if?  the what if is that it will reduce overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Pros

- Easy to implement
- Very flexible

Cons

- Difficult to unimplemented. Once a bunch on lines of code are strone about your code, it can be very time consuming to untangle it. This can be a problem unless the debug code is well structured. There is also a possibility that removing the lines may break timing.
- Overhead. Depending on what processor you use and what capabilities it has, sending a bunch of UART data may tasking and interfere with precise timing.

Other meathods

- A simple LED. Very little overhead to turn lights on and off. Only allows debugging tiny sections of code at a time.
- An in circuit debugger or JTAG debugger specifically meant for you microcontroller. Allows very flexible debug with advanced features such as stepping through code line by line and variable monitoring and injection. Not all processors support this especially low cost ones.

Comment: Check my edit please.

Comment: @h3y4w as long as you are doing anything other than your code (even storing things to memory) the overhead can't be eliminated it can only be reduced.